# .htaccess 2 domains, same target, 1 redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

I own 2 domains that are pointing to the same static ip. I wanted to set **domain1.com** to be redirected to **domain1.com/down.php** but only for the target **domain1.com** and **domain.com/index.php/html**.

The **domain2.com** should work as usual, so no redirects here. It should target */var/www/html* like it currently does.

Background is: that there was a project which should not be available on the **domain1.com**, but there are specific files such as **domain1.com/subdir/subdir/file1.jpg**, which should still be accessible there.

Any ideas?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## .htaccess to redirect domain1.com/*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ down.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

The rule only works if the condition is meet. `?_url=/$1` is not needed but may prove useful.

Answer (score -1):

If you use htAccess, also it seems you use Apache2

You can also use virtual host directly from apache 2 configuration :

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html